# How to show that $|H| = p^n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

If $G$ is an Abelian group of order $p^nm$, where $p$ is a prime that does not divide m, then $G=H \times K$, the internal direct product of subgroups $H = \{x \in G \mid x^{p^n} = e \}$ and $K = \{x \in G \mid x^m = e \}$.

I want to show that $|H| = p^n$. A proof I saw explains that since $p$ does not divide $|K|$, then $|H| = p^n$. I don't understand this however. I only understand that if $p$ doesn't divide $|K|$, then $p^n$ divides $|H|$, but I don't see how they are equal to one another. It's implying that $gcd(|H|, m) = 1$. Can someone please explain this to me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

> **Claim.** Let $q$ be a prime. Let $k$ be an integer prime to $q$. Let $A$ be an abelian group such that for every element $a$ of $A$, $a^k = e$. Then, $\#A$ is prime to $q$.

We show this by the induction on $\#A$. When $\#A = 1$, it's trivial. Otherwise, let $x$ be a nontrivial element of $A$. The quotient $A/\langle x\rangle$ satisfies the assumption of the claim with a smaller number of elements than $A$. Therefore, $q\nmid \#(A/\langle x\rangle)$. On the other hand, $\#\langle x\rangle$ divides $k$ and hence is prime to q. Combining these, we obtain $q\nmid \#A$.

Applying the claim to $K$, we see that $p\nmid \#K$. Applying the claim to $H$ and each prime divisor of $m$, we see that $\#H$ is prime to $m$. Also, $\#H\#K = \#G = p^nm$. By these, $\#H = p^n$ and $\#K = m$.